# Android Brother SDK Label Print Encoding - diacritics

Tags: android, printing, android-print-framework, brother-bpac

I am using Brother SDK to print labels with P-touch template. I have my own template (only with two texts, nothing complicated) in my Brother QL-820NWB label printer.

The printing is working but I have a problem with diacritics. For example "Jan Vomáčka" is not printed correctly. (Problem is `á` and `č`)

I'm using this code from their SDK manual:

```
//Specify the template key and the printer encode
if (startPTTPrint(templateKey, null))
```

And instead of `null`, I tried to set different types of encoding (UTF-8, CP-1250, ...) but nothing works correctly.

I'm not sure what should I change? Maybe something in the label template? But I think I have to somehow set correctly encoding and that will work. But how? What should I set?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ptouch editor for creating template? Try creating template with the default encoding and try transfering template with replaceText by object name in template print.

I have the same objective but it also consist image. It works perfect with text but as you know sdk currently doesn't support replacing image in template type printing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with "ISO-8859-1".